# Maintain scope for a type that changes

Tags: c#

I have a simple bit of code where by I want to set a type depending on some data, but i cannot declare it before hand since i don't know what type it will be set to:

```
if(data[i].on == true){
   Type1   temp  = (Type1)data[i];
} else {
   Type2   temp  = (Type2)data[i];
}
// scope lost
temp.call();
```

How do i maintain scope here? It's a bit confusing because i don't know what type i would have to set `temp` to before the if else statement.

Does C# have a solution for this ?

Comment: do u have an interface for Type1 , Type2 ?

Comment: They inherit but im not using an interface. Type2 inherits type1 so .call() will always work. They both inherit a base class.

Comment: If they both have call() then declare variable as null before the check and use an interface or a base class. If it's impossible then use a delegate like Action and you assign it when you create the types

Comment: This will work if Type1, Type2 have a shared interface with the method .call(), what you can do is use the interface as an object which will solve the issue

Comment: Then declare an in-scope Type1 variable...

Comment: Okay i shall look into learning about interfaces! Thanks!

Comment: If you **know** you can execute `call` afterwards, it means you know something about that object. Therefore, you have to model that, whether it's a base class or an interface. Does `Type2` override the `call()` method? What type is `data`? Is `.on` a public class variable?

Comment: Sorry late reply the reason i have access to call in both is because type2 inherits type1. But i can't set it to Type1 every time because i need to keep the behaviour of type2 as it some times requires references. I'm thinking i might need to add more of my code to the question =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make .call() in Type1 as a virtual method, and override it in Type2, the object in the scope will be from Type1

Base:

```
class VirtualBase
    {
        public virtual void Call()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base Call");
        }
    }
```

Child:

```
class VirtualChild : VirtualBase
    {
        public override void Call()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child Call");
        }
    }
```

Call

```
  VirtualTest.VirtualBase vc = new VirtualTest.VirtualChild();
  vc.Call();
```

Output:

Child Call

Comment: Only if `call` in `Type2` must do something different, we have no info about that.

Comment: if `call` in `Type2` doesn't do something different, he don't need to declare it. it will automatically call the one in the base and the result will be "This is base Call"

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be [dynamic object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

```
dynamic temp;
if(data[i].on == true){
  temp  = (Type1)data[i];
} else {
  temp  = (Type2)data[i];
}
temp.call(); //will work only if both the Type1 and Type2 have call method
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, it doesn't reflect the developer's intentions and it can fail in the future after a tiny change in the code.